# JavaFX - List of table colum of different type

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I need to create a table with: editable cells and columns of different types.

For example, a table with: two string columns, a column of type int and a column of type date. The column with the date for example should display the date picker. A string column must show a textfield and the other string column should display a list of choices.

However, the columns in the future can become many, so I decided to create a method that take the type and the column name from the database that contains the data and create columns dynamically.

This is the code.

```
private String tableName;
private ObservableList<TableColumn<Model, T>> cols = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public Colonne(String tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
}

public ObservableList<TableColumn<Model, T>> Apply() {
    try {
        Connection conn = Driver.connection();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+Driver.getIP()+":"+Driver.getPort()+"/"+Driver.getDatabase()+"?autoReconnect="+Driver.getAutoReconnect()+"&useSSL="+Driver.getUseSSL()+"", 
                Driver.getUser(), Driver.getPassword());

        conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);

        while(rs.next()) {
            if(!rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equals("NUMERO_AZIENDALE") && !rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equals("BOLO") && !rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equals("MARCHIO"))
                switch (rs.getString("TYPE_NAME")) {
                case "VARCHAR": 
                    cols.add((TableColumn<Model, T>) new TableColumn<Model, String>(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").replaceAll("_", " "))); 
                    break;
                case "DATE": 
                    cols.add((TableColumn<Model, T>) new TableColumn<Model, LocalDate>(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").replaceAll("_", " "))); 
                    break;
                case "INT":
                    cols.add((TableColumn<Model, T>) new TableColumn<Model, Number>(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").replaceAll("_", " "))); 
                    break;
            }
        }

        conn.close();        

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        new FxDialogs().showException("Impossibile Verificare i Dati", getClass().getSimpleName(), "2", e);
    }

    return cols;
}
```

But now I can not, or rather, I do not know how to use the two methods: setCellFactory and setCellValueFactory in order to view the data and in order to edit the cells because obviously the data type of the cell is not defined (just look at the above code ).

In fact, by trying the table.getColumns().get(index).setCellValueFactory (...); method, java does not recognize the type.

As the most intuitive and easy solution that I came up, it is to use columns of one type, for example string and still view the date picker etc. Is possibile?

Is there any better solution? or do I have to declare any column?

I hope I was clear, I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way

```
private String tableName;
private TableView<Model> table;

public Colonne(String tableName, TableView<Model> table) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.table = table;
}

public void Apply() {
    try {
        Connection conn = Driver.connection();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+Driver.getIP()+":"+Driver.getPort()+"/"+Driver.getDatabase()+"?autoReconnect="+Driver.getAutoReconnect()+"&useSSL="+Driver.getUseSSL()+"", 
                Driver.getUser(), Driver.getPassword());

        conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);

        while(rs.next()) {
            if(!rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equals("NUMERO_AZIENDALE") && !rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equals("BOLO") && !rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equals("MARCHIO"))
                switch (rs.getString("TYPE_NAME")) {
                case "VARCHAR": 
                    TableColumn<Model, String> columnS = new TableColumn<Model, String>(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").replaceAll("_", " "));
                    if(!rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equalsIgnoreCase("STATO VISITA"))
                        columnS.setCellFactory(col -> new StringCell());
                    else
                        columnS.setCellFactory(col -> new ComboBoxCell());
                    table.getColumns().add(columnS); 
                    break;
                case "DATE": 
                    TableColumn<Model, LocalDate> columnD = new TableColumn<Model, LocalDate>(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").replaceAll("_", " "));
                    if(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").equalsIgnoreCase("DATA PREVISTA PARTO"))
                        columnD.setCellFactory(col -> new LocalDateDataPrevistaCell());
                    else 
                        columnD.setCellFactory(col -> new LocalDateCell());
                    table.getColumns().add(columnD); 
                    break;
                case "INT":
                    TableColumn<Model, Number> columnN = new TableColumn<Model, Number>(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").replaceAll("_", " "));
                    if(!rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME").contains("ID"))
                        columnN.setCellFactory(col -> new NumberCell());
                    table.getColumns().add(columnN);
                    break;
            }
        }

        conn.close();        

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        new FxDialogs().showException("Impossibile Trovare le Colonne", getClass().getSimpleName(), "1", e);
    }
}
```